# How to allow android logging in a shared library?

Tags: android-ndk, android-logcat

I am compiling a 3rd party c library for android app as a shared library. I would like to add android logging to the source code of the c library so I can see what methods gets called, with what arguments. But I can not make it work. I tried the following:

1. Add -llog to Android.mk for the c library

   LOCAL_CFLAGS := := ... -llog
2. Add header file to the source file abc.c where I want to log

   #include < android/log.h>
3. add line

   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "MyApp",  "This is method X");

Error: __android_log_print is not recognized.

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__android_log_print` takes variadic, `printf`-like arguments after the 3rd one. Use

```
__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "MyApp", "This is method X");
```

instead, for no-extra-arguments logging.

EDIT: -llog is a linker flag, not a compiler one. Remove

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := := ... -llog
```

and instead write

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
```

Comment: The error message is the same: error: undefined reference to '__android_log_write'

Comment: That solves the linking error. But the message still does not show up on logcat even I put it at the place I am pretty sure get run.

Comment: Check the logcat filters. Device or emulator? Which Android version - I recall in 4.1 logcat is somewhat restricted.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Android Studio with gradle, it ignores Android.mk. Add this to your build.gradle file:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    ndk {
        moduleName "your_module_name"
        ldLibs "log"
    }
}
}
```